# ggplot2 syntax for grouping boxplots by month?

Tags: r, ggplot2, syntax, boxplot

I have a long dataset with two primary pieces of information - collection date and results. The collection date is formatted as.Date(df, format ="%Y-%m-%d"). I am looking to create boxplots of this data, grouped by month. Using ggplot2 I can create a scatterplot and format the axis by month, but am unsuccessful at changing it to boxplots. Do I need to transform my data to group the boxplots by month? What is the syntax for the aes(group=...) function in ggplot2?

Thank you!

```
ggplot(Results, aes(x = COLDATE, y = `PB(ug/L)`, group=...)) +
    coord_trans(y = "log10") +
    geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5) +
    xlab("Collection Date") +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels =  "%b %Y") +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
```

[image: Screenshot of part of the data.]

[image: Scatterplot of Results]

[image: Unsuccessful boxplot of data]

Comment: I would use `group = lubridate::floor_date(COLDATE, "month")` inside `aes()`

Comment: Thank you! This is close to the final product that I would like! Now is there a way to have each grouped by year? So along the bottom of the graph is January through December, and all of the January boxplots appear next to each other, all of the February appear next to each other, etc.? I realize I need to change my scale_x_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
Results = data.frame(COLDATE = as.Date("2020-01-01") + 1:1000,
                     PB = runif(1000, min = 0.3, max = 18)^3)

library(tidyverse); # or `library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)` or use base to add the year beforehand
ggplot(Results %>% mutate(year = lubridate::year(COLDATE)), 
       aes(x = COLDATE, y = PB, 
           group = lubridate::floor_date(COLDATE, "month"))) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(x = "Collection Date", y = "PB(ug/L)") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels =  "%b %Y") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::log10_trans(),
                     breaks = 10^(-20:20),
                     labels = scales::label_number_si()) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1)) +
  facet_wrap(~year, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Or alternatively:

```
ggplot(Results %>% 
         mutate(year = lubridate::year(COLDATE),
                month = lubridate::month(COLDATE, label = TRUE)), 
       aes(x = as.factor(year), y = PB, 
           group = year)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(x = "Collection Date", y = "PB(ug/L)") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::log10_trans(),
                     breaks = 10^(-20:20),
                     labels = scales::label_number_si()) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1)) +
  facet_wrap(~month, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That looks great. Now let's see if I can get it to run in my environment.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and thank you for your patience.

I am getting the error:
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `year = year(COLDATE)`.
Caused by error in `year()`:
! could not find function "year"

Think I need to install another package or something?

Comment: Whoops, forgot that was from lubridate. edited